# Can I disable notifications fo the default screenshot tool in Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: notification, screenshot

I am currently taking lots of screenshots of online presentations.
I get a notification for them all.
I cannot find a toggle switch in Settings to turn off for ONLY this application.

Where do I turn off the notifications for the "Take a Screenshot" tool s there are no configuration options obvious.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: This question has been asked before and there appears no solution as support for this tool appears to have finished. [see this reference](https://community.upwork.com/t5/Freelancers/Upwork-Team-App-and-Linux-Distro-support/td-p/186451) There is no option in dconf-editor to change the behaiviour either.

Comment: steve lorimer: Not found one yet.  24601 I'm sorry I didn't find the question previously, my apologies. Thanks for the answer though. I'll close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently configurable individually.
All off is only option I can find, which is also possible from script or command line (lots of other answers for this) but `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners false` for off `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.notifications show-banners true` for on again.